# Pip command not recognised by python3.2 on Windows

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to install Pip for Python3.2 on Windows. First off I downloaded the get-pip file for Python 3.2 from the following site:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

and then specifically from the section that reads:

"For the now unsupported Python 3.2, an alternate script is available here."

Once a few fire walls have been disabled, the executables easy_install, easy_install-3.2, pip, pip3.2, pip3 and wheel are installed in:

c:\python32\scripts.

However when I try to run any of these executables in the command-line I get the following error:

```
python 3 exists! Storing in local variable..
path installed is c:\python32
Try to install pip now for python 3...
Now try and install something...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\easy_install.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command.easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\easy_install-3.2.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <modul
e>
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command.easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\wheel.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wheel.tool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python32\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\python32\scripts\pip3.2.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any insight into what this means and how to resolve and get Python32 to recognize pip would be great. As an aside, I also have Python27 installed on the same machine... could this affect things?

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you are trying to get a six year old version of python/pip installed?

Comment: What command did you run there? Can you run `echo %path%` and post the output here?

Comment: Would you mind directing me to the latest version for Python32? Unfortunately due to particular software that we use at work, I am stuck with Python32

Comment: %path% is set as 'c:\python32

Comment: Yeah if you guys have any idea what is going on here I would be massively grateful!